# How to config a flexray node to send a 16 word payload?

Tags: codewarrior, 68hc12

Trying to edit Flexray_UNIFIED_cfg.c in Freescale NCV7383 demo (using CW5.1 and MC9S12XF512) to send bigger packets with different frame IDs to match my automotive target system. Any of youse guys ever grok flexray? Thanks.